# Sliding Menu Like Facebook in Material Design theme in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have made a sliding menu like that of facebook by following the tutorial which is available in the following site: 
http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/05/creating-your-own-sliding-menu-like.html?m=1
Now in the main layout I have added a long paragraph of text so in order to view everything I used ScrollView. But when I use ScrollView I cannot pull the menu out, I can only open the drawer by clicking on the button. Please help me on how to scroll through the para and also be able to pull the menu drawer.

The MainActivity XML file:

```
<info.devexchanges.slidingmenu.SlidingLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- This holds our menu -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarmenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#102961"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_menu_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarmenu"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- This holds our content-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:src="@drawable/menu" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <!-- Fragments container layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

the_fiesta Fragment (the home Fragment) XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="800dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:src="@drawable/fiesta_title"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/the_fiesta"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Java file of MainActivity:

```
package info.devexchanges.slidingmenu;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// The SlidingLayout which will hold both the sliding menu and our main content
// Main content will holds our Fragment respectively
SlidingLayout slidingLayout;

// ListView menu
private ListView listMenu;
private String[] listMenuItems;

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TextView title; //page title
private ImageView btMenu; // Menu button
private Fragment currentFragment;

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate the mainLayout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    slidingLayout = (SlidingLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Init menu
    listMenuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    listMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_menu_listview);
    listMenu.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listMenuItems));
    listMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            onMenuItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        }

    });

    // handling menu button event
    btMenu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_icon);
    btMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Show/hide the menu
            toggleMenu(v);
        }
    });

    // Replace fragment main when activity start
    FragmentManager fm = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    TheFiesta fragment = new TheFiesta();
    ft.add(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment);
    ft.commit();

    currentFragment = fragment;
    title.setText("The Fiesta");
}

public void toggleMenu(View v) {
    slidingLayout.toggleMenu();
}

// Perform action when a menu item is clicked
private void onMenuItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment;

    if (position == 0) {
        fragment = new TheFiesta();
        title.setText("The Fiesta");
    } else if (position == 1) {
        fragment = new ListViewFragment();
        title.setText("Events");
    } else if (position == 2) {
        fragment = new TextViewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("KEY_STRING", "This is a TextView in the Fragment");
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        title.setText("Schedule");
    } else if (position == 3) {
        fragment = new ListViewFragment();
        title.setText("Schools");
    } else if (position == 4) {
        fragment = new ListViewFragment();
        title.setText("Updates");
    } else if (position == 5) {
        fragment = new ListViewFragment();
        title.setText("Our Team");
    } /*else if (position == 6) {
        fragment = new ListViewFragment();
        title.setText("About Us");
    }*/ else {
        fragment = new DummyFragment();
        title.setText("About Us");
    }

    if(!fragment.getClass().equals(currentFragment.getClass())) {
        // Replace current fragment by this new one
        ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment);
        ft.commit();

        currentFragment = fragment;
    }

    // Hide menu anyway
    slidingLayout.toggleMenu();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (slidingLayout.isMenuShown()) {
        slidingLayout.toggleMenu();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
}
```

}

Comment: share your xml file

Comment: Ashish do you want the XML file of the activity or the fragment???

Comment: both the activity and the fragment.

Comment: ok have added both and also the java file

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of Fragments container. add this code below 
`</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` this may work.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_content_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />

    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ashish when i am using this i cannot slide the menu from left to right

Comment: I want the fragment to scroll and also the menu to slide from left to right when we drag